# Link not concatenating the way I imagine it to be

Tags: php, yii

I created this variable to store this string:

```
$extension = '/index.php?Ah83kL80='.$id;
```

And I'm trying to add the $extension to this link:

```
<a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('image/index',array('album'=>$album->content)).'">
```

So far, I tried doing this:

```
<a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('image/index',array('album'=>$album->content, 'index' => $extension)).'">
```

But it put some sort of other characters that I never intended to include.

Output:

```
      /index/%2Findex.php%3FAh83kL80%3D
```

Comment: its good to put the output of the code

Comment: I have added the output of the code as per request

Comment: That still be your $extension varible, however url-encoded. You might want to check PHP urlencode() function for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation I found](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail), the second param is an array of URL parameters. That means that you don't want a string like '?Ah83kL80='.$id but want to pass the `Ah83kL80` key and `$id` value separately, as you're already doing with `album` and `$album->content`.

I'm not familiar with Yii but try building your link like this... I'm going to format this differently than you have so I can indent and make it easier to read.

```
$link = Yii::app()->createUrl(
  'image/index',
  array(
    'album'=>$album->content,
    'Ah83kL80' => $id,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the $id back from the url when it redirects to the next page?

Comment: Certainly. In PHP, you can find URL parameters (HTTP GET Requests) in the $_GET Superglobal, as well as in $_REQUEST. I'd recommend that you read more about [$_GET](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [PHP Superglobals](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), this is a fundamental concept of the language.